# RobotFramework Jenkins plugin is not showing test results when tests are run from argument file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, robotframework

I have 100 regression tests and I am using argument file to run them in specific order. The problem is that RobotFramework Jenkins plugin is not picking up the results. Why?
Thank you in advance,

Olga

Comment: Can you provide any information about the actual order?

Comment: does your argument file include arguments, such as one to turn off the generation of the report, or putting the report in a non-default location? The output of the test should include the path to the generated files, what does it say?